# Window showing in last place rather than first place

Tags: java, jfilechooser

When I use JFileChooser, it opens the dialog window in the last place, not in the first place.

[image]

It is not showing as the first window = it doesn't "pop up" after I run the program.

It works, when I use it in the main, but when I use it in method, it is doing this.

```
import javax.swing.JDialog;
import javax.swing.JFileChooser;

public class JFrameChooser {
    public static void vyberSuboru() {
        JFileChooser fileChooser = new JFileChooser();
        JDialog dialog = new JDialog();
        int result = fileChooser.showOpenDialog(dialog);
        if (result == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
            System.out.println(fileChooser.getSelectedFile().getAbsolutePath());
           }
        }       
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are creating the file chooser with a newly created dialog which is empty and not visible. Instead use your applications's main window as parent.

Something this way:

```
public class JFrameChooser {
    public static void vyberSuboru(JDialog parent) {
        JFileChooser fileChooser = new JFileChooser();
        int result = fileChooser.showOpenDialog(parent);
        if (result == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
            System.out.println(fileChooser.getSelectedFile().getAbsolutePath());
           }
        }       
}
```

Comment: I guess that you have a main window in your application (a JDialog or something similar). You should pass a reference to it as the parent parameter.